# Setting current/compatibility version for a dylib using Netbeans (linux/mac)

Tags: c++, linux, macos, version, dylib

As per the title, how can I set those? Moreover, how can I set versions themselves?

Thanks to all and best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can add build options to your project. You'd need to add *linker* options to set the compatible and current versions according to this page on "Mac OS X for for Unix Geeks": [library version](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/mac/ch05_04.htm). (They use a library called "answer" in their examples, with a supposed current version of 1.2.6)

```
-dynamiclib -install_name libanswer.1.dylib \
  -compatibility_version 1.2 -current_version 1.2.6 \
  -o libanswer.1.2.6.dylib $(OBJS)
```